# Ruby on Rails throws error wihen redirects to root_path or login_path

Tags: ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

I made a simple application that interacts with DB and perform CRUD operations in it after authenticating and authorizing a user. It used to work when there was a single table but as soon as I started playing with nested relations and authentication mechanism I get the error. So far I think I have done everything right. Here's the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Here's my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root to: "todo_lists#index"

   resources :todo_lists do
    resources :todo_items
  end

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  get "/login" => "sessions#new", as: "login"
  delete "/logout" => "sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
end
```

My session controller:

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      def new
      end

      def create
        @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
        @password = params[:password]
      end

      if @user && @user.authenticate(password)
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Logged in successfully"
      else 
        redirect_to login_path, alert: "Invalid Username/Password combination"
      end

      def destroy
        reset_session
        redirect_to login_path, notice: "You have been logged out"
      end
    end
```

Oh and I modified the ApplicationController so the routes should work nonetheless:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :ensure_login
  helper_method :logged_in?, :current_user

  protected
      def ensure_login
        redirect_to login_path unless session[:user_id]
      end

      def logged_in?
        session[:user_id]
      end

      def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code is not in `create` method, and root_path is not a class method, is an instance method:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
    @password = params[:password]
  end # <--- here create method finish. Where this end comes from?

  if @user && @user.authenticate(password)
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    # root_path is defined for an instance
    # of a controller, not for the class
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Logged in successfully"
  else 
    redirect_to login_path, alert: "Invalid Username/Password combination"
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to login_path, notice: "You have been logged out"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for redirecting is outside of the method block:

```
if @user && @user.authenticate(password)
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Logged in successfully"
  else 
    redirect_to login_path, alert: "Invalid Username/Password combination"
 end
```

That code should be before the final `end` of the `create` method

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `root_url` instead of `root_path` in your `SessionsController`?

HTTP requires a fully qualified URL when doing a 302 redirect. The `_url` method provides an absolute path, including protocol and server name. The `_path` method provides a relative path, while assuming the same server and protocol as the current URL.

Try switching to `root_url` and let me know if anything changes!

**Edit:** The reason I suggest using an absolute path is because you mentioned the redirect was working fine with just one table, before you added another table and nested routes.

**Edit:** One other thing I noticed is the authentication block below is not placed within the `sessions#create` route, as you would expect.

```
if @user && @user.authenticate(password)
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Logged in successfully"
else 
  redirect_to login_path, alert: "Invalid Username/Password combination"
end
```

Is there a reason it exists outside of a method? Try moving it back inside the create route.

Comment: Okay. You could also try adding `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to the `SessionsController`. If that doesn't work, I'll keep looking!

Comment: One other thing I noticed is, the user authentication block